# Passport local-auth cookie from Express App is not getting set in Vue3 app with axios

Tags: node.js, express, vuejs3, passport.js, session-cookies

I am creating authentication with **passportjs** local strategy. So I did how it' is supposed to be done. But I don't know if something I am missing here or not.

> **Problem:** After submitting the data from Vue 3 App a cookie supposed to be set in the browser to make sure that the user is
> authenticated. Here the problem is the cookie is not being saved in
> the browser. I tried the same thing with React app and that worked

**Github Link:** https://github.com/abeertech01/vue-cookie-problem-resolve

Here we have all the code.

**Backend (server.js):**

```
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/local-auth")
  .then((res) => console.log(`MongoDB is connected`))
  .catch((err) => console.log("error: ", err))

//Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "http://127.0.0.1:5173"],
    credentials: true,
  })
)

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secretcode",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
)

app.use(cookieParser("secretcode"))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
require("./passportConfig")(passport)

//Route
app.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) throw err
    if (!user) res.send("No User Exists")
    else {
      req.logIn(user, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        res.send("Successfully Authenticated")
        console.log("50 req.user", req.user)
      })
    }
  })(req, res, next)
})
```

I did the passport things in a separate file and that is here in passportConfig,js:

```
const User = require("./user")
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs")
const localStorage = require("passport-local").Strategy

module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.use(
    new localStorage((username, password, done) => {
      User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) throw err
        if (!user) return done(null, false)
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result) => {
          if (err) throw err
          if (result === true) {
            return done(null, user)
          } else {
            return done(null, false)
          }
        })
      })
    })
  )

  passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
    cb(null, user.id)
  })

  passport.deserializeUser((id, cb) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: id }, (err, user) => {
      const userInformation = {
        username: user.username,
      }
      cb(err, userInformation)
    })
  })
}
```

Now in frontend I used axios and the following is the frontend is in the following:

```
const login = () => {
  axios({
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      username: "abeer",
      password: "123",
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    url: "http://localhost:4000/login",
  }).then((res) => console.log(res))
}
```

This is in the `<script setup></script>` tag. In the template tag I ued the function like this: `<button @click="login">Login</button>`

Answer (score 1):

Along with `withCredentials: true` in your Axios request, add `credentials: 'include'`